# APEX date validation ( YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS) using regular expression in javascript

Tags: oracle-apex

I have following code to validate date in format DD.MM.YYYY using regular expression for javascript.I am using this code to validate date in dynamic action on APEX5.0

```
var date_from      = $v('P5_NEW_8');  
var v_valid_from  = date_from.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)\d\d$/);  
var date_to        = $v('P5_NEW_8_1');  
var v_valid_to    = date_to.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](19|20)\d\d$/);  
if (!v_valid_from)  
alert('Date from is in wrong format. Must be DD.MM.YYYY.');  
if (!v_valid_to)  
alert('Date to is in wrong format. Must be DD.MM.YYYY.');
```

where P5_NEW_8 and P5_NEW_8_1 are the items for from date and start date in APEX.
I want to modify above code for format "YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS" .
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression

`^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-]([01][0-9]|2[0123])[:]([0-5][0-9])[:]([0-5][0-9])$`

Valid example is **2015-10-12-20:37:15**